# Updating the AttachmentPart contents without creating new message

Tags: java, soap, saaj

I need to update the AttachmentPart contents inside a SOAPMessage as shown in following figure. I need to keep the headers same.
Is it possible to do it without creating a new SOAP message? I am using SAAJ APIs.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you use the SOAPMessage.getAttachments() call which returns an iterator of all the attachment parts to pull the attachments into a new object, make the necessary modifications, and then call the SOAPMessage.removeAllAttachments() function to clear the objects from the original message and call the addAttachmentPart(AttachmentPart) function to re-add the altered objects?

```
        SOAPMessage message = getSoapMessageFromString(foo);

        List<AttachmentPart> collectionOfAttachments = new ArrayList<AttachmentPart>();

        for (Iterator attachmentIterator = message.getAttachments(); attachmentIterator.hasNext()) {
            AttachmentPart attachment = (AttachmentPart) attachmentIterator.next();
            //**DO WORK HERE ON attachment**
            collectionOfAttachments.add(attachment);
        }

        message.removeAllAttachments();

        for (AttachmentPart newAttachment : collectionOfAttachments) {
            message.addAttachmentPart(newAttachment);
        }



 // This method takes an XML string as input and uses it to create a new
 // SOAPMessage object
 // and then returns that object for further use.
 private static SOAPMessage getSoapMessageFromString(String xml)
           throws SOAPException, IOException {

      MessageFactory factory = MessageFactory.newInstance();

      // Create a new message object with default MIME headers and the data
      // from the XML string we passed in
      SOAPMessage message = factory
                .createMessage(
                          new MimeHeaders(),
                          new ByteArrayInputStream(xml.getBytes(Charset
                                    .forName("UTF-8"))));
      return message;
 }
```

What kind of alterations are you looking to make to your attachments?  Would it be easier to just keep the body in a DOM object and create a new SOAPMessage alltogether?

Comment: A quick question, how do I create a new SOAP message from the SOAPPart of previous message ?
Keeping all the headers, meta info identical ?

Comment: Hmmm, if you have to retain identical header content without regenerating the values, I'd have to do some digging into that one.

With the method above, you're actually reusing the original message object with all the headers you already added to it upon construction - you're only stripping and readding the `attachmentPart` attributes.

Comment: Depending on how you're constructing your messages, @BhushanKarmarkar , you can do the following to get the contents of the headers:

`MimeHeaders headers = message.getMimeHeaders();`

Then, once you've pulled the headers out, you can destroy the old SOAPMessage object, create a new one, and re-add the headers object you extracted.

Comment: I've recently added one more challenge I am facing while dealing with attachments. Kindly have a look and let me know if you can provide any pointers on it:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28872259/identifying-datahandler-source-type-for-a-soap-attachment